# Was verse 3.7.2 of Brihadaranyaka upanishad, a forerunner to Sri Krishna's statement in BG?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, brihadaranyaka-upanishad, vayu

The verse [3.7.2](http://www.upanishads.kenjaques.org.uk/Brihadaranyaka_Upanishad_Chapter_Three.html) of Brihadaranyaka upanishad says :

> He said, 'Vayu, O Gautama, is that Sutra. Through this ***Sutra or Vayu
>   this and the next life and all beings are held together***. Therefore, O
>   Gautama, when a man dies, they say that his limbs have been loosened,
>   for they are held together, O Gautama, by the Sutra or Vayu'.'Quite
>   so, Yajnavalkya. Now describe the Internal Ruler'.

It says vAyu binds all being together indicating vAyu a Cosmic Spirit or God.

---

Vayu is called Brahman in [Shanti Mantra](https://greenmesg.org/stotras/vedas/om_shamno_mitrah_sham_varunah.php) - ***Namo brahmane namaste vaayo twameva pratyaksham Brahmaasi.***

---

Sri Krishna says in BG 7.7 as follows:

> मत्त: परतरं नान्यत्किञ्चिदस्ति धनञ्जय | मयि सर्वमिदं प्रोतं सूत्रे
>   मणिगणा इव ||
>
> There is nothing higher than myself, O Arjun. Everything rests in me,
>   as beads strung on a thread.

---

My question is whether verse 3.7.2 of Brihadaranyaka upanishad, a forerunner to Sri Krishna's statement in verse 7.7 of BG?

Comment: In a vague way, Yagyavalkya is talking about Vayu or Prana. https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_1/Raja-Yoga/Prana .God itself is Prana and Akasha or Time(Time Period-repetitive motion of Heart and cause for blood circulation within body) and Space in which everything exists and Krishna is talking about Brahman as the thread base for both.

Comment: Vayu is called Brahman in Shanti Mantra - **Namo brahmane namaste vaayo twameva pratyaksham
Brahmaasi**. @Manu Kumar

Comment: Yes Prana/Vayu itself is Brahman as its a universal phenomenon controlling life span, metabolism of all beings. Segregated Vayu, Agni, Akasha etc., serve no purpose but together and in synchronization they are manifestations of Brahman just like Man is made of several organs and parts. Is your leg or hand not you yourself?

Comment: I am not contesting anything.  If you know the answer, please provide it. @Manu Kumar

Comment: Do you mean whether Krishna's saying is based on particular verse of Brihadaranyaka Upanishad?

Comment: @Paṇḍyā: I have not concluded anything.  I had expressed my doubt.  One must be forerunner to the another.  It is OK for me, if it is the other way around also.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv It's ok. Bhagavad Gita is mostly based on Upanishads. But which verse is related to or belongs to which is the area of research.

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely that the Brihadaranyaka verse is the forerunner of the Bhagavad Gita verse. The Bhagavad Gita verse refers to Krishna as Brahman, supporting everything. But the upanishad verse refers to vAyu. In the subsequent verses (3.7.7), the upanishad mentions that vAyu is controlled by the Internal Ruler (antaryAmi). This antaryAmi is Brahman.

> Verse 3.7.7:
>
> यो वायौ तिष्ठन्वायोरन्तरः, यं वायुर्न वेद, यस्य वायुः शरीरम्, यो वायुमन्तरो यमयति, एष त आत्मान्तर्याम्यमृतः ॥ ७ ॥
>
> yo vāyau tiṣṭhanvāyorantaraḥ, yaṃ vāyurna veda, yasya vāyuḥ śarīram, yo vāyumantaro yamayati, eṣa ta ātmāntaryāmyamṛtaḥ || 7 ||
>
> 7. He who inhabits the air but is within it, whom the air does not know, whose body is the air, and who controls the air from within, is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self.

Comment: Many Rig Vedic Verses mention Vayu as brAhman

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Thats fine. But in this context that you have asked, vAyu is not brahman. There are also other verses in upanishads which say that vAyu is controlled by brahman.

Answer (score 0):

The [Brihadaranyaka Upanishad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brihadaranyaka_Upanishad) is one of the Principal Upanishads and one of the first Upanishadic scriptures of Hinduism.

The Brihadaranyaka Upanishad is estimated to have been composed about 700 BCE, excluding some parts estimated to have been composed after the Chandogya Upanishad. The Sanskrit language text is contained within the Shatapatha Brahmana, which is itself a part of the Shukla Yajur Veda.

---

I am quoting [one of the answers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38821/3869) in this site, below:

According to the introduction to K. K. Shastri's The Jaya-Saṃhitā (The Ur-Mahābhārata) much of the Mahābhārata story we know today ***including the Bhagavad-gītā*** is a late addition to the text.

> A puzzling problem before us is of ***godly or super-human
> characteristics of Kṛṣṇa and Śiva. It is quite easy to find out that
> wherever such narrations come, they are easily discardable***, and their
> absence is very much helping us in restoring the flow of the
> narration. ***They are all inserted at later dates when both of them were
> established as supreme gods after the expiry of the old Upaniṣadic
> period.***
>
> As for Bhagavad-gītā (23 to 40 adhyāyas in the Bhīṣma-parvan) we are
> not in a position to include it wholly, or its any part, not only in
> the Bhārata but perhaps not even in the Mahābhārata.

---

According to the introduction to K. K. Shastri's The [Jaya-Saṃhitā (P.23)](https://archive.org/details/jaya_samhita_the_ur_mahabharata_introduction_kk_shastri/page/n13/mode/1up), the original version of Mahabharata, ie., ***Jaya Samhita*** of Sage Vyasa, contains 8,800 slokas only.  And, Bhagavad Gita is not the part of Jaya Samhita.

---

Thus, we can infer that verse 3.7.2 of Brihadaranyaka upanishad, is a forerunner to Sri Krishna's statement in verse 7.7 of BG, as BG is itself is a later date addition to Mahabharata.